# Is it possible to modify private member of a class directly from main?

Tags: java

I have created a private class member of stack and don't know how it gets accessed directly or indirectly from main method although i havn't used any object for it. When program executes the sorting method, it directly modifies the private member "stk[]" automatically.

This is the code which modifies the private String stk[] indirectly from main method when sorting option is called from main method:

```
import java.io.*;
class Stack
{
   private String stk[];
   private int tos;
   private int size;
   Stack()
   {
      size=5;
      stk=new String[size];
      tos=-1;
   }
   Stack(int sz)
   {
      size=sz;
      stk=new String[size];
      tos=-1;
   }
   boolean push(String s)
   {
      if(tos==size-1) return false;
      stk[++tos]=s;
      return true;
   }
   String pop()
   {
      if(tos<0) return "Stack Underflow";
      return stk[tos--];
   }
   String[] display()//array type function to return an array called "stk"
   {
      return stk;
   }
   int returnSize()
   {
      return tos;
   }
}
class myStack
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {
      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      Stack S=new Stack();
      int opt=-1;
      while(opt!=6)
      {
         System.out.println("\n\n\n");
         System.out.println("[1] - Create Stack");
         System.out.println("[2] - Push");
         System.out.println("[3] - Pop");
         System.out.println("[4] - Display");
         System.out.println("[5] - Display List In Ascending Order");
         System.out.println("[6] - Exit");
         System.out.print("Option: ");
         opt=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
         if(opt==1)
         {
            System.out.print("\n\nEnter the size of stack: ");
            int size=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            S=new Stack(size);
            System.out.print("\nStack Created...");
         }
         else if(opt==2)
         {
            System.out.print("\n\nEnter String: ");
            String s=br.readLine();
            if(S.push(s))
               System.out.print("\nSuccessfull...");
            else
               System.out.print("\nStack Overflow...");
         }
         else if(opt==3)
         {
            System.out.print("\nItem Deleted: "+S.pop());
         }
         else if(opt==4)
         {
            int sz=S.returnSize();
            System.out.print("\n\n\nStack Contains: "+(sz+1)+" Item(s)\n");
            String st[]=S.display();
            while(sz>=0)
            {
               System.out.println(st[sz]);
               sz--;
            }
         }
         else if(opt==5)
         {
            int s=S.returnSize();
            String stc[]=S.display();
            for(int i=0;i<=s;i++)
            {
               for(int j=i+1;j<=s;j++)
               {
                  if(stc[j].compareTo(stc[i])<0)
                  {
                     String t=stc[i];
                     stc[i]=stc[j];
                     stc[j]=t;
                  }
               }
               System.out.println(stc[i]);
            }
         }
         else if(opt>6)
         {
            System.out.print("\nPress 6 To Exit....");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: it **is** possible - with reflection - but why don't you just make the field protected or public?

Comment: Waay too much irrelevant code -- please boil it down to the essential parts. Furthermore it's unclear what the actual question is.

Comment: You can also use the `switch` statement instead of `if-else` all the way...

Comment: It is also possible if the main method is in the same class than your private variable.

Answer (score 1):

**I think this is what you're on about..**

```
String stc[]=S.display();
       for(int i=0;i<=s;i++) {
         for(int j=i+1;j<=s;j++) {
             if(stc[j].compareTo(stc[i])<0) {
                  String t=stc[i];
                  stc[i]=stc[j];
                  stc[j]=t;
             }
         }
         System.out.println(stc[i]);
        }
```

When you call `S.display`, you're passing a reference to your array, and storing that reference in `stc`. `stc` then is modified, but because `stc --> array <--- stk`, you're going to edit both.

Answer (score 0):

Private means you can't access it outside the class even in main and i think it is not good pratice if your member are private and you want to access them outside then why you want to access them outside if they are private. make it public see below.

```
public class Stack
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

private means just that.  The value is not visible outside of the class it belongs to.

You can change it with reflection but you shouldn't.  If it's your class the member belongs to then write a public method to get/change the variable. If it's not your class then the value isn't intended to be visible / changed directly.  Change this (with relection) at your peril.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, it is important to make a difference between [immutable and mutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

**Immutable objects cannot be changed after they have been created**

For example:

```
String s = “foo”;
```

It is impossible to change the String object which is referenced by the variable `s`. The object will always contain the data “foo”. If you do `s.concat(“bar);`, the String object referenced by `s` will not change. Instead, the method call will return a completely new String object which is the concatenation of “foo” and “bar”.

**Mutable objects can change**

For example:

```
List<Integer> l = new List<Integer>();
```

The above is an empty list object. However, if we call `l.add(42);` we have actually changed the List object referenced by the variable `l`.

**Why is this distinction important?**

If you want to encapsulate implementation details in your class, you cannot return any private instance variables which are references to mutable objects through the public interface of your class.

That is what is happening. You are returning a reference to the private `stk` array. But arrays are mutable, and hence the returned reference can be used to modify the referenced array object.

**How to prevent this?**

One way is to use [defensive copying](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15). This means that you should return a copy of the mutable object, instead of the mutable object itself.
For example:

```
String[] display() {
    Arrays.copyOf(stk, stk.length);
}
```

This way, any changes performed in the client code that uses the returned reference will only influence the copied object, and your private array object will remain intact.